# How to Check Delivery Availability depends on zip code on magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, shipping, javascript, mysql

I would like to develop simple solution for checking availability based on zip codes. If the zip code available in database it should display shipping available for your location else shipping not available. how to do this in magento ?

Comment: Look into this extension if helps
https://magecomp.com/magento-cod-checker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a quick search at `magento connect` for a module and found this one:
[http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-filter-by-zip-code.html][1]

I believe it will give you a solution.
If you try it out write back a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try below extension . this will work fine for you

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-restriction.html